# Angular web service call with select2 plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Angular for my first time in a project where I use Bootstrap and Thymeleaf. I have to substitute this thymeleaf code

```
<div class="form-group" id=existingUser>
    <label>Username</label> <select class="form-control select2"
        style="width: 100%;" th:field="*{user}">
        <option th:each="user: ${users}" th:value="${user.username}"
            th:text="${user.username}"></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

with angular because I have this select in my modal form and each time user opens this modal I have to update this field ().
So I have written this code

```
<div class="box-body" ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="freeUserController" class="form-group"
        id=existingUser>
        <label>Username</label> <select class="form-control select2"
            style="width: 100%;" name="user">
            <option ng-repeat="user in users" value="{{user.username}}">
                {{user.username}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

and in my javascript file:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('freeUserController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'users'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.users = response.data.result;
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
});


$(function() {
    $("#createLicenseButton").click(
            function() {
                var form = $("#addLicenseForm");        
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : form.attr("action"),
                    data : form.serialize(),
                    // all right with rest call
                    success : function(data) {  
                        //No exception occurred
                        if (data.status==true){ 
                            //Also the field are right(for e.g. form value)
                            if(data.success==true){
                                //il risultato sta in data.result
                                //window.location.reload(true);
                                location.reload();
                                //reload only the tag with id carsTable, so only the table
                                //$('#carsTable').load(document.URL +  ' #carsTable');
                                $('#addLicenseModal').modal("hide");
                                notifyMessage("Your license has been created!", 'success');
                            }
                            else{
                                //code if there are some error into form for example
                            }
                        } else {
                            //code exception
                            $('#addLicenseModal').modal("hide");
                            notifyMessage("Error! Your license hasn't been created!", 'error');
                        }
                    },
                    //error during rest call
                    error : function(data) {
                        window.location.href = "/ATS/500";
                    }
                });
            });
});
```

But I have some problem:

1. when I have only an element in select field and if the user select
   it, this is not showed in the field but it is saved in my form
   variable.
2. With thymeleaf one element is selected as default, now how can I set a defeault element (any one)
3. How can I call angular http call when the modal is clicked or in success ajax call?

Comment: You should look into using the [AngularJS-native version of Select2 and Selectize](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select).

Comment: Also try to use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat` on the `<option></option>`

Comment: with ng-options the problem one is resolved, but if I add $scope.selectedItem = $scope.users[0]; it returns to not work